# where can I find the resources for programmers exchange's theme?

Tags: discussion, design

I really love the theme used for this exchange. Is there any resource that could be reused or some reference (fonts, graphics, css, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main font of the site is [Whiteboard Regular](http://www.fonts2u.com/whiteboard.font), and as far as I know you can use it freely in your projects.

Everything else is copyrighted by Stack Exchange. You'll have to contact them directly (["contact us"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer) to discuss what you can and cannot use.